# undefined service response in controller to store in variable using angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a factory, calling the service and getting the response and passing in to the controller and trying to store the response in a variable which is getting undefined

```
app.factory('Myservice', function (service1, service2) {
    return {
        getService: function (data) {
            service1("user", encodeURIComponent("pass")).then(function (response) {

                varSessionData = response.Obj;

                var queryString = strURL[1].split("&");

                Service2.pageLoad(SessionData).then(function (response) {
                    var homeScreen = response;

                    data(homeScreen);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In Controller:

```
var Mydata = MyService.geService(function (data) {
    Console.log(data);
    return data; // getting response
});

$scope.Hello = Mydata; // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following, your data isn't defined synchronously.

Controller:

```
MyService.geService(function(data) {
  $scope.Hello = data;
});
```

Comment: i have pass the $scope.Hello in Another Service controller,which means depend upon that taking the result    Service3.pageLoad($scope.Hello)
       .then(function (response) {
      
           $scope.ServiceModelobj = response;
           console.log(response);
}

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make any **A**JAX request they are asynchronous. That is why Angular promises are used (the `.then` method). So you should change your code like this in your controller:

```
MyService.geService(function (data) {
    Console.log(data);
    $scope.Hello = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have pass the $scope.Hello in Another Service controller,which means depend upon that taking the result  from services.

Not working?

```
var HomeController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $stateParams, $state, Service3, Myservice)
{

MyService.geService(function (data) {
    Console.log(data);
    $scope.Hello = data;
});

Not working
  Service3.pageLoad($scope.Hello) // not get the value
       .then(function (response) {

           $scope.ServiceModelobj = response;
           console.log(response);
}
```

Working code

```
var HomeController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $stateParams, $state, Service3, Myservice)
{

MyService.geService(function (data) {
    Console.log(data);
    $scope.Hello = data;

 Working//
  Service3.pageLoad($scope.Hello) // get the value
       .then(function (response) {

           $scope.ServiceModelobj = response;
           console.log(response);

});
}
}
```

Comment: In your first example, the first service method runs, and then the second service method runs immediately after, before the first call has resolved. In your second example, you are calling the second service inside the callback of the first, so it has at that point been defined.

Comment: In the Second example, i have using Second service inside the first service thats what its return ok , but my question is there any other way to pass the first service response globally, which i don't want to put the second service inside of first service. See first example in undefined i need to get the value  tats my problem.